# How to limit cells linked to multiple spinners in a row to the sum of the value in the cells which the spinners are linked?

Tags: excel, vba

I have got 5 spinners linked to 5 cells in a row. Is it possible for the spinners to stop working when the sum of the 5 cells reaches a certain value?

i.e not being able to increase any cells further until you reduce another cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for, it's a little hacky but does the job.  Make sure you follow all steps otherwise you'll run into problems.

In your workbook, add this code to a new module ...

```
Public Sub Spinner1Change()
    SpinnerChange "Spinner1"
End Sub

Public Sub Spinner2Change()
    SpinnerChange "Spinner2"
End Sub

Public Sub Spinner3Change()
    SpinnerChange "Spinner3"
End Sub

Public Sub Spinner4Change()
    SpinnerChange "Spinner4"
End Sub

Public Sub Spinner5Change()
    SpinnerChange "Spinner5"
End Sub

Sub SpinnerChange(ByVal strSpinnerName As String)
    Dim bEnabled As Boolean, strLinkedCell As String, objSheet As Worksheet

    Set objSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    If Range("rngCurrentValue") > Range("rngMaxValue") Then
        strLinkedCell = objSheet.Shapes(strSpinnerName).ControlFormat.LinkedCell
        objSheet.Range(strLinkedCell) = objSheet.Range(strLinkedCell) - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Change "Sheet1" to be the name of your worksheet where your spinners exist.

Now in your worksheet ...

[image: Worksheet]

.. create 2 named ranges:

- **rngCurrentValue** (Linked to cell **H2** in my example)
- **rngMaxValue** (Linked to cell **D2** in my example)

With your spinners, give a sequential name to each one, I've called them Spinner1, Spinner2, Spinner3, etc. and link them to the desired cells ...

[image: Spinner Configuration]

Enter in a max value (as show in cell **D2**) and then spin up to it and it should result in the last spin being decremented down to it's prior value.

There's no error checking as such but you can work through that yourself, I feel that's only fair.

if you get a better solution, feel free to take it.  :-)

Comment: Cheers boss, ill have a try when i get back from work and will let you know if it works!!!

Comment: @JoshAlton I forgot to say and it may be obvious but the rngCurrentValue cell needs to be a sum of all spinner values.

Comment: Thanks again, ive just done it and it seems to be working. Thanks for the help skin!

Comment: @JoshAlton cool man, just do me a favour and flag it as the answer.  Thanks